# Get absolute coordinates of view inside popup window

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-popupwindow, android-window

I have a draggable popup window fragment. I need to get the x and y coordinates of that fragment in onSaveInstanceState(). I got the width and height of the fragment by using `getView().getWidth()` and `getView().getHeight()`. But if i use `getView().getX()` or `getView().getY()` giving 0.0. Is there any chance to get the coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`View#getLocationOnScreen(int[])`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[])) API:

> Computes the coordinates of this view on the screen. The argument must be an array of two integers. After the method returns, the array contains the x and y location in that order.

```
    int[] location = new int[2];
    getView().getLocationOnScreen(location);
    // now location[0] contains x position
    // and location[1] contains y position
```